# Hatcher Example 0.14 - Quotient of $X \cup CA$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $(X,A)$ be a CW pair where $A$ is contractible. Example 0.14 of Hatcher's Algebraic topology states that upon contracting $A$ in the mapping cone, $X \cup CA$, of the inclusion map $A \rightarrow X$, the resulting space is homotopy equivalent to the mapping cone of a constant map, $X \vee SA$. I was wondering if the following reasoning is of how to show this is correct:

Contracting $A$ (identified as a subspace of $X$) in the CW complex $X \cup CA$ gives $(X \cup CA)/A =  X/A \vee SA$ where $SA$ is attached to the point representing $A$ in $X/A$. Now as $A$ is contractible $X/A \simeq X$. Lastly we want to show that $X/A \vee SA \simeq X \vee SA$ where the space $X \vee SA$ has one of the "vertices" of $SA$ attached to an arbitrary point of $A \subset X$. Now viewing $A$ as a subspace of $X$ in the CW complex $X \vee SA$ we can quotient out this copy of $A$ to yield $X \vee SA \simeq X/A \vee SA$, giving the result.

Comment: looks fine to me. I think you meant "inclusion map $A \to X$" but yeah that is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your reasoning is correct. I have given a slightly more detailed argument below.

Recall that any CW pair satisfies the homotopy extension property. Since $A$ is contractible, we have homotopy $h:A\times I \to X\cup CA$ with $h(-,0)$ the inclusion, $h(0,1)$ a costant map, and which has image in $A$. By the extension property, we get homotopy $H:(X\cup CA)\times I\to X\cup CA$ with $H(-,0)=\text{id}$ and $H(-,1)$ mapping $A$ to a point. Since $H(-,1)$ maps $A$ to a point, it induces a map $(X\cup CA )/A\to X \cup CA$. Denote this map by $\psi$. Let $\varphi: X\cup CA \to (X\cup CA )/A$ denote the quotient.

We now claim that $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are homotopy inverses i.e. $\psi\varphi \simeq \text{id}$ and $\varphi \psi\simeq \text{id}$. This will show the wanted since $(X\cup CA )/A\simeq X\vee SA$. Note that $\psi\varphi\simeq \text{id}$ via the homotopy $H$. Since $H|_{A\times I}$ has image in $A$, we get induced homotopy on quotients $\widetilde{H}:(X\cup CA )/A\times I \to (X\cup CA )/A$ which gives $\varphi \psi\simeq \text{id}$.

Edit:

I realise now that the question was how we got the homotopy equivalence $(X\cup CA )/A\simeq X\vee SA$ since on the nose $(X\cup CA )/A = X/A\vee SA$. It is in fact by the same reasoning as above. Namely consider the pair $(X\vee SA, A)$ which has the homotopy extension property since it is a CW pair. By the same argument as above, we get that the quotient $X\vee SA\to (X\vee SA)/A=X/A\vee SA$ is a homotopy equivalence. This is precisely the argument you did in your solution.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me (actually the main reason why I asked the question) that $(X \cup CA)/A = X \vee SA$. Rather, it seems(?) to be the case that $(X \cup CA)/A = X/A \vee SA$ because the subspace $A$ that is quotiented out of $(X \cup CA)$ appears not only in $CA$ but also in $X$.

Comment: I see that i misread your question a bit and have added an edit which hopefully answers it a bit better.